# Why is my entity framework context not updating after adding column to database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Basically there's simple application that I've made for EF testing. I added DataModel, then created data source object just like MSDB tutorial says.

DataBinding works good, but problem appears when I add or delete column from sql table (eg. in SSMS `ALTER TABLE xxx ADD yyy varchar(50)`).

Is it possible to update/refresh data model without me ? I mean, I don't want to run IDE and click "Update Model from Database", because users will add new columns massively. Is Entity Framework even good for this idea ?

Comment: Please provide more info about what steps to take and what happens? any errors? Also you can read here to check if you are doing right: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/changing-the-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't because it makes no sense and is technically impossible. How would it work?
When is this updating supposed to happen? Should a database have a permanent connection to your context and data model and update it whenever schema changes? What happens if you have thousands of connections, what would happen then? Also, do you really expect the change in the database schema to change your c# code? Can database change the compiled code (dll), or just source?

And, apart from these technical questions, your database model is not your domain model. Usually they correlate, but that is not always the case. I had a few applications where c# code had fewer objects than the database had tables and these object didn't need all the columns in the database.

So, no, this would be quite unusable or completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Framework you have two choices.
1. Create a Database and generate a Model from it
2. Create a Model and generate a Database from it

Entity Framework does not do this in real time, optimally you choose one you want to use and do it once, you can always delete the old Database and generate a new one (if using option 2) or delete the Model and generate a new one (when using option 1)

Option 1 is called a "Database first" approach, meaning that any changes to the data model are done in the Database and your Model has t be adjusted/ regenerated
Option 2 is called a "Code First" approach, meaning changes to the data model are done in the Code classes and be migrated to the Database

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you are using the 'database first' aproach based on your question, if so; have a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/changing-the-database).

If you are using a 'code first' approach, then have a look at [migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/).

Comment: Thanks, it works. But the question is if it possible to update without doing anything (in this case clicking Update Model From Database) ?

Comment: Maybe create some context for us on what/why you are trying this? The problem as mentioned in other comments is that this kinda flies in the face of ORM's. In the end you want to use whatever data is in the database, so you need to be able to predict the structure and logic of the data so you can use it inside your code. Given your reply that users should be able to change this, id imagine a different aproach to how users can add their own data (structuraly) is more usefull. But we would need more context to form an answer i guess :)

Comment: No, it is not possible. The model is part of your code base. What you are trying to do is (if I read your comments correctly) to update the model while the code is running, which would require the code to replace its own binaries, which is impossible. Even if you were to extract your model into another solution, you'd have to update references on the fly. So, if I read that correctly, there are technical difficulties that prevent solutions (that are not really EF related IMO).

Comment: I wouldnt say its impossible, its just opposite of what an ORM like EF is meant for. An ORM maps a table structure to a concrete object that you can use in your code. This makes it easy to use the database object in your code because the structure and contents is predictable. You _could_ offcourse write your own database logic, query the table structure and map that to a dynamic object. But its a lot more complicated and takes a lot more work than an out of the box ORM would. Something in the middle would be an ORM like Dapper. Or, revisit the decision to let users alter tables.